# Видимость iframe'а

Tags: php, вконтакте, vk-mini-apps

Я создал приложение типа vk mini-apps, вставил туда фрейм, как положено

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body>
    <iframe src="https://мой_сайт/rm-mobile/page.html" width="700" height="560"></iframe>
</body>

</html>
```

На мобильных устройствах вечная загрузка. Мобильная версия на пк показывает это:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И опять же с вечной загрузкой. Как с этим бороться?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Проблема решена. Я выбрал неверный тип приложения